# Type Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo

This is the code I implemented for adding data to collection:

```js
import FirebaseKeys from "./config";
import firebase from "firebase";
import "@firebase/firestore";

class Fire {
  constructor() {
    firebase.initializeApp(FirebaseKeys);
  }
  addPost = async ({ text, localUri }) => {
    const remoteUri = await this.uploadPhotoAsync(localUri);
    const desc = text;

    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      // console.log("THIS FIRESTORE" + this.firestore);
      const dbh = firebase.firestore();

      // this.firestore.collection("posts").add({
      //     text: desc,
      //     uid: this.uid,
      //     timestamp: this.timestamp,
      //     image: remoteUri
      //   })

      dbh
        .collection("posts")
        .doc("feed")
        .set({
          text: desc,
          uid: this.uid,
          timestamp: this.timestamp,
          image: remoteUri
        })
        .then(ref => {
          res(ref);
          console.log("EVERYTHING IS FINE HERE");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log("ERROR HERE TOO");

          rej(error);
        });
    });
  };

  uploadPhotoAsync = async uri => {
    console.log(this);

    const path = "Date.jpg";
    return new Promise(async (res, rej) => {
      const response = await fetch(uri);
      const file = await response.blob();

      let upload = firebase
        .storage()
        .ref(path)
        .put(file);
      upload.on(
        "state_changed",
        snapshot => {},
        err => {
          console.log("ERROR IN PHOTO UPLOAD");

          rej(err);
        },
        async () => {
          const url = await upload.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
          res(url);
          console.log("IMAGE IS UPLOADING FINE");
        }
      );
    });
  };
  get firestore() {
    return firebase.firestore();
  }

  get uid() {
    return (firebase.auth().currentUser || {}).uid;
  }

  get timestamp() {
    return Date.now();
  }
}

Fire.shared = new Fire();
export default Fire;
```

I'm building an app using expo react native and using firebase for data manipulation.
But while using function for adding data to collection, it shows error like

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')

Help me out anyone

[SCREENSHOT OF THE ERROR](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mbQG.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

Update: the problem is being addressed [here](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2858) and should be fixed in v7.13.3.  I previously stated that downgrading to firebase v7.9.0 fixed the issue.  I discovered that the issue does not exist until v7.13.2.  So we can downgrade to v7.13.1. However, we must completely uninstall firebase for this to work.

I experienced the same error with expo and firebase.  I am using Expo version 37.  To fix the problem I had to downgrade firebase using the following commands in my app's directory:

```
npm remove --save firebase 
npm install --save firebase@7.13.1
```

If I use firebase version 7.13.2 I get this error:

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')

Comment: what function are u using to send data to firestore?

Answer (score 0):

A comment from another question has a solution: I had the same issue. Downgraded the firebase version to @7.12.0 and it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue here. I found out that my expo client on android was updated by google play. Latest version use expo sdk 37.
I just ran expo update in my project and everything is working again

Answer (score 0):

The answer given here (downgrading) worked.
In my case though, upon downgrading, I saw that the real error was a permission error (production mode).

So the real issue is that this error is masking whatever the real error is. Hopefully it gets fixed soon.