# Firebase "Type Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')" Problem

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo

I upgraded to Expo 37 from 32 but I started getting some error like this.

[image]

I see that problem is throwing from firestore when I want to using code like that

```
firebase.firestore().collection("anycollection").get().then();
```

and I tried thats

[StackOverFlow Solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028557/type-error-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-wu-getrandomvalues)

but I still facing this problem.

Expo 37,
Firebase 7.13.2

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
firebase.firestore("anycollection").get().then();
```

into this:

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
db.collection("anycollection").get().then();
```

Check the guide:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: Hi I writed wrong . But this issue not about that you write. Just Im write wrong