# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Uo.getRandomValues') Firebase/firestore react-native

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this error while trying to a access a firestore collection

Here's my firebase config

```
import Firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";

let config = {
  apiKey: "xxx",
  authDomain: "xxx.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://xxx.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "xxx",
  storageBucket: "xxx.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "xxx",
};

let fb = Firebase.initializeApp(config);
let firestore = fb.firestore();

export const db = firestore;
export const auth = fb.auth();
export const firebase = fb;
```

Import and usage in a component:

```
import { db } from "./src/plugins/firebase";

      db.collection("collection")
        .doc(docId)
        .collection("subcollection")
        .doc(subdocId).set({
        some object
      })
```

I've seen similar issues like in: [Type Error undefined is not an object (evaluating 'Wu.getRandomValues')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61028557/type-error-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-wu-getrandomvalues)

So I downgraded firebase to 7.9.0 but it didn't fix it...

Also this is only happening when running react-native bundle with option --dev false, if --dev true I don't get the error...

Answer (score 1):

I finally made it work... I've tried everything removing firebase deleting package-lock.json clear npm cache and reinstalling firebase@7.8.2 but none of those worked... What worked was switching to Yarn instead of npm... so I just did a yarn add firebase@7.8.2 and it's up and running again.